# Node.js alongside .Net libraries

Tags: .net, node.js, architecture

I'm not sure if this question has either been asked or is in the correct stack site. - let me know if it isn't and i'll gladly remove it.

I'm a .Net-stack developer; more specifically, Web. I also enjoy many of the tools and frameworks .Net has to offer.

I also develop a lot with JavaScript, and various frameworks such as Angular. Especially over the last couple of years.

As I develop more JS I'm finding myself intrigued by Node.js and the strengths it has. I admit, I don't know a great deal about Node.js other than some of the typical `hello world` examples out there.

Now, I would rather not have to learn a whole bunch of other frameworks to replace some of the ones I use in .Net - such as Entity Framework for example.

So this lead me to wonder - is there anything available that bridges the gap between Node and .Net.

Perhaps my thought process isn't working correctly, though what I would like to achieve would be:

- Front end with something like Angular
- Calling a Node.js Rest API
- Node then reaching out to business layers built with .Net

I figure with this, that I would/could get the speed and scale-ability that Node.js offers but keep in with the many years of experience I have with .Net for everything between the Rest service and Database.

Is this something that exists, or even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is entirely possible.

Think of a node.js application as an http server on it's own, just like your .net server. They can both co-exist on the same physical(or virtual) server running on different ports. You can then bring them both under the same domain and port using IIS (or apache, nginx, etc) reverse proxy settings. With that setup, all it would take to communicate between the two is a simple http call, and your front end would look like it's all running under one system, even though in reality they're two separate applications.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking - just use Node.js for the server requests only. You lost me on the rest of the post though - using IIS. Would this be site -> node -> IIS -> Other .Net libraries (doesn't seem right..)

Comment: look at it this way. I have a coldfusion application running on port 80, on domain `http://www.example.com`. I also have a node.js app running on port 5000, `http://localhost:5000`. To make the node.js app publicly available, i can use a reverse proxy in iis  to forward all requests to `http://www.example.com/api` to `http://localhost:5000`. From the outside, it would look like you're requesting from the same server and port (and ajax requests would all be same-origin, no CORS bullshit), but you're not, they're actually two servers.

Comment: The company I currently work for is breaking out of a PHP monolith in this exact same manner. We run a reverse proxy with apache to our node app and do all communication between the 2-3 apps via http. Has worked beautifully. After you get your feet wet with node, I suggest looking into [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) for managing long running node processes.

Comment: though, if you're using windows, windows services work pretty well for keeping node processes running too, and best of all, the two can be combined. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the last few years there is a new Software Architecture trend called Microservices.

Essentially the idea behind Microservices is to have multiple, small and specialised applications over a monolithic application.

What you are describing is exactly that, decoupling your web app (possibly written in Node) from all the Business Logic (that can be one or more applications) written in .Net

As well as giving you the flexibility of choosing the best language/technology for a specific task, this gives you the ability to scale your application easily and effectively.

You can read more about it [in this post](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html)

EDIT: also as described by Kevin B, you can use http calls to communicate between those applications. And to add to that you could also use pub/sub or queues for communications between microservices

Comment: Ah, great, thanks :) That link is super helpful too. And now I know there is a trend, and what it's called, it'll help me no end :)